# Size of byte blocks

Tags: java, compare, size, arrays, block

I need to compare different files on duplicates using the blocks of bytes.
But I have a question and unfortunately can't find an answer on it.

What size of blocks (byte-arrays) is optimal and why?

Comment: Why not test it? Besides, how can you be sure there's a single optimal value that would be the best with every hardware configuration?

Comment: Right you are!
But I don't even know where to start about

Comment: I heard [42](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29) is a good number. Give it a try, and see if it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

Start by comparing the file size. If that ain't equal, they are not duplicates. If your comparison passed that check, you don't have to care for performance anymore, since that part won't be reached often.